# Power Transmitting and Receiving from antenna of same frequency?

Tags: rf, power-electronics, antenna, power-transfer

I want to ask something about power transmitting and accepting. If we have a source antenna of 2.45GHz and a receiver antenna of 900MHz. Could the receiver accept the power transmitting by the source? or we have to use source and receiver of same frequency? Please guide me. Thank you!

Comment: There is nothing so black and white about antennas.

Comment: Yes they can. But how well? Look at the frequency response curves of your antennae. Do they meet your link budget?

Comment: Like others have said, it all depends.  What you are asking about is the bandwidth (BW), or the instantaneous bandwidth (IBW) of the antenna.  Antennas can be designed with a relatively narrow IBW (say 5% of the center operating frequency), or a very wide IBW (10:1 or 20:1).

Comment: To begin with: are you asking if the 2.45GHz device can interfere with the 900MHz one or are you asking if you can use a 900MHz antenna to pick up 2.45GHz signals?

Comment: Yes Mr. @Lundin

Comment: It wasn't a yes or no question...

Comment: I was asking for the receiver of 900MHz receiving power from a source of a 2.45GHz antenna.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. However if you designate an antenna at a certain frequency (2.45 GHz and  900 MHz), it is assumed these antennas are resonate at those frequencies. That means they are designed to be most efficient at those frequencies. Thus if you transmit at 2.45 GHz, the 900 MHz antenna will receive thoses signals but output a much lower level than if it was receiving a 900 MHz signal. For best results, both the transmitting and receiving antennas should be resonant the same frequency.